# connect points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have attached a sample plot code. The x-axis is discrete (chr type), y axis is numeric.

1. How do I join points to see the change in count with days i.e. connect points of same color
2. I want x-axis to be in the pre-defined sequence (not alphbetical) i.e. - "Sun", "Mon", "Tue"

```
days <- c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue")
count <- c(1, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 4.5)
variant_type <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")

tbl <- tibble(days, count, variant_type)

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = days,
           y = count,
           color = variant_type)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to accomplish this, you will need to explicitly define the grouping structure by mapping group to the `variant_type` variable from within the `ggplot()` aesthetic, where it will be applied to all layers. Then you simply have to map the `colour` aesthetic to the `variant_type` variable within `geom_point` and `geom_line`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

days <- c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue")
count <- c(1, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 4.5)
variant_type <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")

tbl <- tibble(days, count, variant_type)

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = days,
           y = count,
           group = variant_type)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = variant_type)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = variant_type)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>